# How to pack all project files(not just dll) into single executable?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have recently started learning C#. I have been working on a project to learn .Net core. When I build my project it generates one dll, some json and one pdb file along with the exe file. To run the exe file, those other files needs to be in the same directory. How can I pack all these files into the exe files?

Comment: [Making a tiny .NET Core 3.0 entirely self-contained single executable - Scott Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingATinyNETCore30EntirelySelfcontainedSingleExecutable.aspx) and [Publish .NET Core apps with the CLI - .NET Core | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli#self-contained-deployment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to publish it with `PublishSingleFile`. Please see [What's new in .NET Core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#single-file-executables)

> `dotnet publish -r win10-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true`

Comment: yes, I have published and there's those files too, same as the build.

Comment: I have done it by adding XML property in the csproj file.